# xslt passing parameters from java

Tags: xslt

I am trying to pass parameter from java to XSLT V2.0

I tried all solutions found in web sites. But could not get it working.

From Java I have given as below:

**transformer.setParameter("abcd", strMessageHeader);**

And in XSL I have as following

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:param name="abcd" /> 

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:param name="abcd" /> 
    <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="abcd" /> 
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/RequestPayload">
    <xsl:param name="abcd" /> 

<Hdr>
    <xsl:value-of select="*[name()=$abcd]" />
</Hdr>

  .
  .

</xsl:template>
```

I also tried like below

```
<xsl:value-of select="$abcd" />
```

Nothing seems to work. Can someone help me on this.

Comment: Did you ever find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

As far as you declared param abcd as global (directly under xs:schema element) you have not to declare again in template because it is accessible from it.

So remove local declarations of abcd parameter and remain only the global one. Also remove with-param clause in apply-templates.